# .htaccess Check if client isn't requesting index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I met a problem when making my contact form. My .htaccess file is working for URLs like:

```
ex.com/a -> ex.com/a.php
ex.com/b -> ex.com/b.php
...
```

But when I do `ex.com`, it causes an error 500.

The problem I have found is that .htaccess's output for this is `ex.com/.php`. But I don't know how can I fix this. This is my .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks for the help in advantage.

**Edit 1**

I have tried to add the following conditions

```
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.php -f
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index.php -f
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\index.php -f
```

Still error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^$` and `RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]`? Also, check your server log files.

Comment: is your mod_rewrite really enabled? check ini_set('display_errors', 1);  what does the log in your apache or php produces on error messages.

Comment: @kmoser this seems to work for index.php, but now links like ex.com/a aren't working

Comment: @ChristianFelix If mod_rewrite isn't enabled, then how links like ex.com/a would work

Comment: @LambdaTheDev "Aren't working" meaning what?

Comment: Returning error 404.

Comment: you are not forced to use mod_rewrite while calling ex.com/a. There are enough method to achive the same without this module.

Comment: Like creating 50 folders and index.php in each? I want to do it using mod_rewrite, just need to have this 1 condition I am trying to achieve...

Comment: I have found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries and more research, I have found this pattern that determinates, if the string is empty:

```
^\s*$
```

Then, I took my .htaccess file and added the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^\s*$
```

It checks if the request filename is not empty. And of course, if it is empty, it cancels the rewrite.

So full .htaccess file is from now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^\s*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When I make a request `http://ex.com/a`, it shows me `http://ex.com/a.php`. But if my request is just a `http://ex.com`, then it displays me the content of the index.php file.